# Laravel Scout (Meilisearch) - Says imported data, but doesn't

Tags: laravel, full-text-search, laravel-scout, meilisearch

I've installed and configured meilisearch + Laravel Scout package.

My Model:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    use Searchable;
}
```

When I run `php artisan scout:import 'App\Models\Post'` it returns:

```
Imported [App\Models\Post] models up to ID: 5
All [App\Models\Post] records have been imported.
```

But when I check the index, it's empty. Why?

> The index is being created, but the data doesn't get imported.

> The same configuration of meilisearch and Scout package, works for some other models.

Comment: Hi! What does the update status return? https://docs.meilisearch.com/reference/api/updates.html#get-all-update-status

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've just run into this issue myself and came across your question. I don't suppose you're specifying what should be stored in the index are you?

I.e. in your model, have you created a `toSearchableArray` method like the below...

```php
public function toSearchableArray(): array
{
    return [
        'name' => $this->name,
    ];
}
```

If you have, it turns out that your `toSearchableArray` method **must** also return the primary key within the array, otherwise the record does not get indexed.

```php
public function toSearchableArray(): array
{
    return [
        'id'   => $this->getKey(), // this *must* be defined
        'name' => $this->name,
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks this fixed my issues :)

Comment: For this particular model I was hiding the primary key, and removing it was spot on. Thanks!

Comment: That solved my issue as well! without the id, it doesn't get indexed, it's a meilisearch specific thing tho as it is not explicit on laravel's scout doc.

Answer (score 6):

You can try to set:

```
SCOUT_QUEUE=false
```

To check that there is no issue with your queues and run the import again.

Comment: I had tried it before, and it didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

For index you can try:

`php artisan scout:index posts`

There is no other issue with your queues and run the import again.

If you have `SCOUT_QUEUE=true` then please, start your queue using `php artisan queue:work --daemon` and your data will be start importing.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you dont have a scope in your model or comment it out:
`php artisan scout import`

doesnt have a session so if your scope is something like `user_id == auth()->id` will not work.